# How to boot the Linux kernel with initrd or initramfs with gem5?

Tags: gem5

With QEMU, I can use either use `-initrd '${images_dir}/rootfs.cpio` for the initrd, or pass the initramfs image directly to `-kernel Image`.

But if I try the `initramfs` image with gem5 `fs.py --kernel Image` it fails with:

```
fatal: Could not load kernel file
```

with the exact same initramfs kernel image that QEMU was able to consume.

And I don't see an analogue to `-initrd`.

The only method that I got to work was to pass an `ext2` disk image to `--disk-image` with the raw `vmlinux`.

https://www.mail-archive.com/gem5-users@gem5.org/msg15198.html

Answer (score 0):

initrd appears unimplemented on arm and x86 at least, since gem5 must know how to load it and inform the kernel about it's location, and grepping `initrd`only  shows some ARM hits under:

```
src/arch/arm/linux/atag.hh
```

but they are commented out.

Communicating the initrd to the kernel now appears to be simply doable via the DTB `chosen` node `linux,initrd-start` and `linux,initrd-end` properties, so it might be very easy to implement: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/chosen.txt (and gem5's existing DTB auto generation) + reusing the infrastructure to load arbitrary bytes to a memory location: [How to preload memory with given raw bytes in gem5 from the command line in addition to the main ELF executable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60993870/how-to-preload-memory-with-given-raw-bytes-in-gem5-from-the-command-line-in-addi)

Initramfs doesn't work because gem5 can only boot from vmlinux which is the raw ELF file, and the initramfs images only gets attached by the kernel build to a more final image type like Image or bzImage which QEMU can use to boot, see also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/5518/what-is-the-difference-between-the-following-kernel-makefile-terms-vmlinux-vml/482978#482978

Edit: the following is not needed anymore after the patch mentioned at: [How to attach multiple disk images in a simulation with gem5 fs.py?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862906/how-to-attach-multiple-disk-images-in-a-simulation-with-gem5-fs-py/60210181#60210181) To do this test, I also had to pass a dummy disk image as of gem5 7fa4c946386e7207ad5859e8ade0bbfc14000d91 since the scripts don't handle a missing `--disk-image` well, you can just dump some random 512 bytes and use them:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=dummy.iso bs=512 count=1
```