# Mounted linux filesystem access

Tags: linux, mount, gem5

I am running gem5 in FS mode. I have put some comments in gem5 to create a file in some path(say /root).
But it is unable to create file in the path of virtual system.

I dont think it is permission issue?

Please help why its not able to access the folder of virtual system.

I am checking in those path(/root) after the virtual system boots up.

Comment: Hi Rashmi, is the root filesystem mounted as read-write? Either with `rw` kernel CLI option, or `mount -o remount /`? On future questions, please provide the actual commands ran, and precise error messages, otherwise it is hard to know what is going on. Also try stuff out on QEMU which boots much faster, and move to gem5 once you understand what is going on.

Comment: I am not sure how gem5 mounts the image. I want to generate some logs when the gem5 system is booting up in FS mode.(want to capture some addresses of boot process) What should I put the logs path?? beacuse our host system path ll not be accessible to it and virtual system path is not ready by then probably.

Comment: You should always give you full gem5 CLI and gem5 revision, and usually terminal logs and gem5 stdout, and any scripts you modified to increase chance of getting a reply. In this case, I think fs.py cannot mount multiple images, you need a patch: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50862906/how-to-attach-multiple-disk-images-in-a-simulation-with-gem5-fs-py